# Error while completing batches in Azure functions w/Service Bus Trigger

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am implementing an queue which is used by an api, dequeued by an azure function and inserted into a database. I want to bulk insert into db to improve performance. However I am  experiencing some issues when completing multiple messages myself.

By setting `autoCompleteMessages: false` the code underneath works fine.

```
[FunctionName("BatchProcessingFunc")]
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("eventbatches", Connection = "QUEUE_CONNECTIONSTRING")] Message myQueueItem, 
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver, 
    ILogger log)
{

    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(myQueueItem.SystemProperties.LockToken);        
}
```

However once i change `Message myQueueItem` to `Message[] myQueueItem` it suddenly starts to throw an `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException`. Code which triggers an exception:

```
[FunctionName("BatchProcessingFunc")]
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("eventbatches", Connection = "QUEUE_CONNECTIONSTRING")] Message[] myQueueItem, 
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver, 
    ILogger log)
{

    foreach(var message in myQueueItem)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {message}");
        await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }           
}
```

Complete exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.DisposeMessagesAsync(IEnumerable`1 lockTokens, Outcome outcome)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.CompleteAsync(IEnumerable`1 lockTokens)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<<StartMessageBatchReceiver>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

CompleteAsync seems to work the first time, however it seems like the function tries to complete it again once more. Which obviously wont work as that message already is completed.

I need to control which messages is completed or abandoned myself,as some messages may fail and some may succeed in the same bulk-write.

Any ideas to what might be wrong, fixes or eventual workarounds would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if a typo, but have you set `autoComplete: false` or `autoCompleteMessages: false` ? Docs say to use the latter instead of the former

Comment: Yep, you're correct. Its a typo. Fixed it now. Thanks @AdaTheDev

Comment: Did you mean that when you fixed your typo , your code worked or you just fixed typo in your question.